# Matching BBCode content and attribute via regex

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I use the PECL BBCode class in an older project to manage BBCodes, which works very well. For some special cases, it doesn't suffice, because I need to run a function over input. So I want to do this with regex before the PECL thing is runnning.

I want to match the [member]-tag with as well as without attribute:

```
[member]Donald Duck[/member]
[member=Dr. Donald Duck]Donald Duck[/member]
```

I can match them this way:

```
\[member\](.+?)\[\/member\]
\[member=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/member\]
```

How can I do this in one step? I made the = optional with ? but it doesn't match both. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `=` to the optional group:

```
\[member(=.*?)?](.+?)\[\/member]
        ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nLA2ha/1)

**Details**

- `\[member` - a literal `[member` substring
- `(=.*?)?` - Group 1: an optional sequence of `=` and then any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `]` - a `]` char (no need to escape it)
- `(.+?)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\[\/member]` - a literal `[/member]` substring.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i appreciate that. Directly used, your regex throws a "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash", I think because the square brackets aren't masked? But I used the `(=.*?)?` part in my regex and it worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: @degers [Here is the demo code](https://regex101.com/r/nLA2ha/1/codegen?language=php). You may use `'~\[member(=.*?)?](.+?)\[/member]~'`